# Does a clearTimeout abort an aysnc XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, timer, xmlhttprequest

I am calling  a function recursively and in that function I am requesting update info from my server.

This is the calling function:

```
    function StartFeedUp() {
        GetNextImage();
        if (tmrStartFeedUp) window.clearTimeout(tmrStartFeedUp);
        tmrStartFeedUp = setTimeout(StartFeedUp, 100);
    }
```

This is the function being called:

```
            var urlTS = '/Cloud/isNewFrames.ashx?alias=' + alias + '&version=' + version + '&guidlogon=' + guidlogon;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", urlTS, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            var nextts = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //do something with info
```

when the time limit of 100ms is reached is the XMLHttpRequest aborted or should I also use a timeout on the rest call?

Comment: NO, setTimeout has nothing to do with the Ajax call

Comment: `nextts` will most likely be _undefined_ because as soon as you call `xmlhttp.send()`,  your `xmlhttp` has gone _async_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearTimeout` will just prevent the function from being called again. It should not prevent any actions taken within. With that said, `clearTimeout` does not seem very useful in your case. It looks like you chain the `setTimeout` calls one after the other, and in this case `clearTimeout` is useless because when you enter the function the timeout is already cleared.

In your case I would suggest using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, and call `clearInterval` to interrupt the function calls.

Comment: a _setTimeout_ chain is safer than a _setInterval_ (consider what happens when something takes longer than the _interval_ to complete it's invocation) You are correct about it not being helpful in this instance, though.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to find a structure to do all this. I was thinking of using a web worker and to postmessage back when there is an update. That web worker would recall itself.  I am struggling to find a way to do this to be honest.

Comment: @PaulS. That's right, but then it all depends whether it's more important to call the function on a regular basis or to wait a minimum time between two calls.

Comment: But, you did answer my initial question :)

Comment: I will 'tick' this when the system allows me. Should I post my requirements as a seperate question?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson considering it's not an issue with clearTimeout on  XMLHttpRequest, I think it'd be better to create a dedicated question.

Comment: I completely agree :)